# Simple javascript game: Object creation error due to constructor or conditional operators

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, conditional-statements

I'm fairly new to java and I've been slowly building up a game. I know there are different ways to write objects, but after a recommendation, I built them like this model:

```
function object(x,y,z){
    var object={
    a:x,
    b:y,
    c:z
    };
    function doSomething(){
        ...
    }
    return object;
}
```

Everything was going great until I made my "player" shoot a bolt. The bolt are objects and each newly created bolt is stored in an array. Here it is:

```
var playerBolts=new Array();
```

This is the method that is called inside the "player" object when he shoots:

```
function shootBolt(){
    playerBolts.push(bolt(player.playerNum,player.facingLeft,player.x,player.y));
}
```

The bolt is shot from the player's current position and depending on the direction he is facing, the bolt will move in that direction obviously. To let the bolt know which was it has to travel, I have a boolean in my bolt's object constructor called "facing" (player.facingLeft above). When I use that boolean in a ternary operator to give a directional speed, it always gives me an error: "ReferenceError: facingLeft is not defined".

This is bolt object that is created:

```
function bolt(fromPlayer,facing,playerX,playerY){
    var bolt={
        playerNum:fromPlayer,
        damage:10,
        facingLeft:facing, //The direction at which the bolt moves, if left, true
        x:playerX, //The x position of the bolt
        y:playerY, //The y position of the bolt
        xSpeed:facingLeft ? -3 : 3, //The horizontal speed at which the bolt is moving
        ySpeed:0, //The vertical speed at which the bolt is moving
        W:3, //The width of the bolt's model
        H:3, //The height of the bolt's model
        color:"red", //The color of the bolt's model
        update:update,
        draw:draw
    };
    function update(){ 
        ...
    }       
    function draw(){
        ...
    }
    return bolt;
}
```

If I remove the ternary operator and just set xSpeed to a predefined value, all the other variables in the constructor seem to pass along just fine. So I'm really wondering what I'm doing wrong here... I tried doing an if/else statement, but I get: "SyntaxError: missing : after property id".

Do I have have to change all my objects to a different model or is there something I'm not seeing? If this is unclear, I can always provide more information or code.

Thank you?! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can't refer to an object while it is building. If you use 'this' when computing the property value, you'll use the current context, not the new object :

```
function someFunc() {
    var functionThis = this;

     var aNewObject = {
                        a : 3,
                        b : this.a *2   // nAn : this.a == functionThis.a                                           
                        }

     // this will be working :
     aNewObject.b = aNewObject.a * 2;
   }
```

So when you refer to 'this.face', it will give : undefined, so the ternary operator
will always switch to the falsy case.

In your very case the solution is simple : use the facing arguments instead of trying to get the facingLeft object property :

```
    xSpeed:facing ? -3 : 3,
```

2) if you are using a lot of bolts, think about setting the methods on the prototype for faster creation and less garbage creation.

Comment: Sooooo yep, that fixed it wonderfully, thanks, didn't know about this :) I basically did the same, but outside (and right after) the var bolt={} i added:   bolt.xSpeed=bolt.facingLeft ? -3 : 3;

Comment: However for your 2) I'm not quite sure what that is or how you do that... is there a term on google or a post I could look at for information on that?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `facingLeft ? -3 : 3` with `facing ? -3 : 3`, since you cannot reference the property of an object not yet created (namely "facingLeft").

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/ct3Ht/)**.

Comment: And holy dam that was it...guess at 4 in the morning here things start to lose perspective xD Thanks for that and the link!

Comment: @VincentPiel: I tried with both "true" and "false" and it worked fine. What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I might have spoken too soon. I can actually see a bolt now instead of an error message, it doesn't respond to the ternary operator and always moves in the same direction whether facingLeft is true or not :(

Comment: @ExpertSystem : you are not testing the right item property : it is xspeed that is the issue here, and it is the same wether facing right or left.

Comment: @AlexanderWeihmayer: Sorry, for that. I updated my answer and the short demo.

Comment: @VincentPiel: You were right. Answer updated. Thx for the heads-up.

Comment: That also works! Thanks a lot guys I kinda get where all this is coming from now!